# clinfo shows "Number of platforms 0"

Tags: opencl, centos7, nvidia

I'm developing on Centos 7.6 64bit and Nvidia graphic card.
I've installed Nvidia driver and cuda driver.

But, when I run "clinfo", it shows:

```
Number of platforms                               0
```

What should I check and how can I solve it?

Comment: First, you should check if Nvidia platform is enabled for OpenCL ICD: run `cat /etc/OpenCL/vendors/*` to find out all enabled platforms.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/`, `nvidia.icd` exists. And the result of `cat /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd` is `libnvidia-opencl.so.1`.

Comment: In `/usr/lib64` and `/usr/lib`, `/usr/lib/libnvidia-opencl.so.1` are linked to `libnvidia-opencl.so.410.93`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cuda's nvidia driver and your display nvidia-driver should match. I faced this problem yesterday and solved it but installing nvidia-driver suggested in cuda run file. 
make sure that `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/<version>` links properly with kernels.
see my topic for more info.
[Sample deviceQuery cuda program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54668169/sample-deviequery-cuda-program)

Comment: Thanks. Had the same issue. What I did was running `dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia` and updated all the packages that were listed.

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation @carnicer